# Do some radial engine planes have a two-speed starter motor?

Tags: piston-engine, engine-starting

[image]
([YouTube](https://youtu.be/G5IWNSaC6ME?t=2m1s))

Watching the Connie fire up her engines I wondered, do some radial engine planes have a two-speed starter motor to replace the ground crew "[pulling the props through](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29561/14897)"?

In other words, low-speed–mags-off to test for a potential hydraulic lock.

I do realize the props could have been *pulled through* off-camera before being towed out for the show.

Comment: It appears from the other answer that hydraulic lock is only a problem after the plane has sat for a long period. Might not be necessary to pull through if the plane has been flown that day

Comment: Btw, have you ever heard a Connie? A place in Gardner KS works on them and when they test fly it you can hear it in the next county

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be only one starter speed:

> Proper sequence for starting radial engines...DC-6B style, with P&W
>   R-2800's.
>
> - Engage start and start safety switches.
> - Rotate thru 9 blades.
> - While continuing to rotate the engine with the starter, engage primer and
>     ignition boost switches, and at the same time, select magnetos to
>     'both'.
> - When engine fires, continue starting with the fuel primer
>     engaged, releasing the start and start safety switches.
> - Slowly move
>     mixture control to the autolean position, then release fuel prime
>     switch.
> - Engine continues to run (hopefully).
> - Taxi in autolean, until
>     engine run-up desired.
> - Complete run-up and propellor checks in
>     autorich.
> - Return mixture to autolean.
> - Prior to takeoff, ensure engine
>     mixture controls are in autorich (very important).
>
> Have a pleasant day, thereafter (hopefully). ;-)
>
> DC-3 about the same, except...
>
> - use autorich for all ground ops.
> - Engine
>     type, P&W R-1830-92.
> - Curtis Wright engines...can't remember.
>
> Stratocruiser, same as the DC-6B. DC-7 and Lockheed 1649, same also,
>   as the DC-6B.
>
> NB. Operating in autolean helps to prevent plug fouling while on the
>   ground.

[[Posted by *411A* on May 18th, 2008 at pprune.org]](http://www.pprune.org/aviation-history-nostalgia/327485-old-aircraft-engine-starting-methods.html#post4123165)

Comment: TIL auto-lean is a thing. :)